# Copy an item list with a kind of condition WHERE

Tags: workflow, metadata

I would like to know if it's possible with SharePoint designer 2010 (foundation) to copy an item from a list to an another list WHERE this another list name = targeted first list column value ?

For example I got 4 lists.  List "market", list "fruits", list "vegetables", list "other".

In "market" list I have a column "kind". The values of this column can be : "fruits", "vegetables" or "other". When I approve my item apple (so fruits) I would like to copy this item in the "fruits" list.

The values of this column is in each time equal to the name of the lists.

How can I copy/range my item in terms of this column value ? I have to check all conditions ? I would like to factor precisely...I made this column to avoid this fact.

Comment: I can't edit my post so "Hi all"

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with the "language" of workflows, so I may not be describing this in the terms that you are familiar with, but, if your field values are *exactly* the same as the other list names, couldn't you do something like this? (Sort of pseudo-codey, but describes the steps needed.)

```
Get current item "kind" field value and store in variable "kindValue"

Copy current item to list named "kindValue"
```

Comment: It was my idea I just do not know how to create this syntax. When I do "actions" > "then Copy item in Current Item to xxxxxx" . xxxxxx is necessarily a physical list (I do not recall my variable " kindValue ". What to do? Best regards, Elmata

Comment: If you cannot select or specify the list to copy to based on the variable, then you will have to create multiple if/thens, and check all conditions.

Comment: Oh my god, I was afraid, that sucks :S

Comment: Sorry i'm despite :(